# current directory in string command to run a file

Tags: java, eclipse, string, processbuilder

i have already asked a similar question but i have changed up my code a little bit. i am in the making of an application that opens other applications from a usb, like a hirens boot cd menu toolbox. my problem now is that every time i plug my usb into another computer with java file and tools the directory changes. for example if my script is...

String command = "E:/IPRESET.bat"

than when i connect the usb to another pc than it might change from E to J, or whatever.

i wanted to know if there is a way to replace E,J,K or whatever with a code to set the current java file directory so it changes for every computer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question then yes. A file in the current folder could be accessed with something like,

```
String command = "IPRESET.bat";
File f = new File(command);
if (f.exists()) {
    try {
        System.out.println(f.getCanonicalPath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Note**: It's a really good idea to make sure the [`File.exists()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29) before you try and use it.

Also, you could possibly use [`File.listRoots()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listRoots%28%29) to *List the available filesystem roots* and iterate them to check for your script like

```
File[] roots = File.listRoots();
for (File r : roots) {
  File f = new File(r, "IPRESET.bat");
  if (f.exists()) {
    // ...
  }
}
```